# How can i retrieve a list that lies within a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble accessing the list value inside my dictionary. I want to find the list of the player's results using their name, which is my key. when I try to run this nothing happens. I believe there's an error in the logic.

```
x=int(input())
search_player=input()
if 2<=x<=10:
    player_results={}
    for i in range(x):
        player,*pol=input().split()
        scores=list(map(float,pol))[:3]
        player_results[player]=scores
    for key,value in player_results.items():
        if key==search_player:
            print(value)
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do?

Comment: I would recommend changing the variable `x` to something that specifies its use a bit more. See [What are “symbolic constants” and “magic constants”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951017/5763413)

Comment: I want to get the list of any player's scores by searching their usernames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the value of a dictionary `d` for a particular `key` using `d[key]` or, even better, [`d.get(key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which allows you to specify a default value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. You don't need to iterate over the dictionary.

Try this instead:

```
x = int(input("Enter the number of players: "))
search_player = input("Enter the player to search for: ")

if 2<=x<=10:
    player_results={}
    for i in range(x):
        player, *pol = input(f"Enter name and scores for player {i}:\n").split()
        scores = list(map(float,pol))[:3]
        player_results[player] = scores
    
    print(player_results.get(search_player, "Invalid player name"))
```